# Migración AngularJS a Angular, archivos básicos de configuración

Tags: angular

Acabo de empezar en Angular, sólo llevo una semana de curso y me surgen un montón de dudas.

He conseguido un pequeño proyecto en AngularJS que me interesa evolucionar en Angular y TypeScript.

Después de ejecutar los *"npm install"* indicados en el proyecto me da error al ejecutar el *"ng serve"* pues entiendo necesita los archivos básicos tipo tsconfig.*, angular.json, ...

He intentado adaptar los de otro proyecto sin éxito.

¿Cómo se generan estos archivos?

Muchas gracias, Xavi

---

Gracias por vuestras respuestas.

El objetivo que me piden es hacer la migración, ya me gustaría poder reescribir los pocos módulos que contiene el proyecto. Quizás una semana de curso es poco para hacer algo así.

El mensaje inicial obtenido con el *ng serve* fué:

*The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.*

Supongo que era normal por faltarle los archivos generales de Angular.

Después de intentar "generar" los archivos el mensaje es:

*An unhandled exception occurred: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
See "C:\Users\xavie\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-VjMLls\angular-errors.log" for further details.*

Es decir, el log contiene esta información:

*[error] TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

```
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xavi\cursos\Angular & TypeScript\MaterialAlten\star-wars-master\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\CssDependency.js:12:46)

at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)

at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)

at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)

at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xavi\cursos\Angular & TypeScript\MaterialAlten\star-wars-master\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\index.js:14:45)

at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)

at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)

at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)

at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xavi\cursos\Angular & TypeScript\MaterialAlten\star-wars-master\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\cjs.js:3:18)

at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)*
```

Comment: Qué error te muestra al ejecutar ng serve?

Comment: Angular y AngularJS son totalmente distintos. En lugar de intentar evolucionar el proyecto en AngularJS es más práctico hacer  uno nuevo en Angular. Puedes ver la guía de migración: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Comment: Para migrar el proyecto en AngularJS a Angular, primero debes saber como funciona  Angular. No se trata solo de generar  los archivo base de Angular, simplemente no funcionaría.

Comment: La idea no era pedir ayuda para la migración, sólo cómo consigo generar los archivos básicos de Angular (tsconfig.*, angular.json, ...) sobre un proyecto existente en AngularJS. A partir de aquí ya intentaré avanzar como pueda.

Comment: Buenos días, finalmente parece que puedo crear un nuevo proyecto Angular en lugar de evolucionar sobre el mismo de AngularJS. Gracias por vuestros comentarios.